# I want to get base64 string value in ajax form post

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller

I want to get this value in ajax form post

```
<input type="hidden" id="Base" value="iVORw0KGgoAAAANSUh......"/>
```

input type have base 64 string

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var BaseImage = $('#Base').val();
    var baseImageContent = BaseImage.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    var blob = baseToBlob(baseImageContent, 'image/png');
    var base = blob;
    var noOfPeople = $("#NoOfPeople").val();
    formData.append('Base64Image', blob);
    if (noOfPeople == '' || officer == ''  || VillageId == '' || DistrictId == '' || BlockId == '') {
        alert("Fill Information...!!!!!!");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://coll.org/API/PukarRegister",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg)   
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
        });
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You did not ask any question. Please be clear on what you want to achieve and on what is happening instead.

Comment: I want to get base64 string in ajax form and post to the server

Comment: You still did not explain **what the problem is**. Also, please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51784666/edit) to add your clarification, that is easier for new people reading it so they don't have to dig through the comments.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can encode o decode a string using these functions:

```
function utf8_to_b64( str ) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( str )));
    }

    function b64_to_utf8( str ) {
      return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob( str )));
    }

    // Uso:
    utf8_to_b64('✓ à la mode'); // "4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU="
    b64_to_utf8('4pyTIMOgIGxhIG1vZGU=');
```

[More information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_codificando_y_decodificando)